# How does the internal energy and entropy depend on mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, energy

I've found this thermodynamics question:

> Given a fluid described by the following equations:
>
> $$PV^{1/3}=aT^3 ,\quad U=3aT^3V^{2/3}, \quad S=\frac{9}{2}aT^2V^{2/3}$$
>
> The parameter $a(n)$ is a positive function of the amount of substance $n$.
>
> **How does $a(n)$ depend on $n$?**

$a(n)$ should increase if $n$ increases (since both are extensive), so I think that the most obvious answer would be that it's a linear relation. This would be the case of an ideal gas, where:

$$U=C_VT$$

But, **is it possible that $a(n)$ is non-linear or is there any reason we can restrict the behaviour of $a(n)$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $V\propto n$, since $P$ and $T$ are intensive quantities, the first equation implies that $a$ it's proportional to $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$. As you can see this also works good with the other two.

I'm not sure that is always the case that $V\propto n$, though. Since $n$ is directly proportional to the mass, which is directly proportional to the volume through density, this would be the case if the density was not constant.

Comment: I see. You're using the fact that $T$ and $P$ are intensive, right?